# How can I fix my encrypting with OpenSSL and decrypting in Java using AES?

Tags: java, openssl, aes

I'm struggling on this problem: I want to encrypt a password with openssl, and decrypt it in java.

Here's what I have for the moment:

```
String aesKeyBase64 = "BDC17ABE1F194C8DD49840C57A155013";
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(aesKeyBase64), "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

// encrypt
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal("password".getBytes());
String encodedPassword =  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText); //returns ITmSsa+9aKeW776ABM5B+g==
System.out.println("encrypted password = " + encodedPassword);

// decrypt 
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
cipherText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode("b3JCq/QmtKSmkQABYdbiVA==".getBytes()));
System.out.println("decrypted password = " + new String(cipherText));
```

Here's my openssl command:
`openssl enc -nosalt -aes-128-ecb -base64 -K BDC17ABE1F194C8DD49840C57A155013 -in in.txt -out out.txt`
which returns b3JCq/QmtKSmkQABYdbiVA== in the file out.txt

So I noticed that my two encryption are different, with aes-ecb there isn't IV, I haven't used salt, and pad is set to PKCS5 which is default pad with openssl enc

When I tried to decrypt openssl enc result here's my Java output:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.

I made sure to use a generate my key in Java directly with a string key to ensure I'm using same key in both methods.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So, by using code from here : stackoverflow.com/a/65955135/15410702, I manage to understand what is causing issue The shared code works well, but the openssl enc commande don't encrypt in base64 I would like to add a -base64 (same as -a) in this command like to fix my issue, back to Java I would replace ``cipher.doFinal(cryptedData)` by `cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cryptedData))` to decrypt a base64 content

But I'm ending with this error : `Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 24`, how can I fix it ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

**Your key is not base64.** It is hex (aka hexadecimal).

It's pretty obvious just looking at it, but you can also use logic: it is 32 characters, and a 16-byte key (for AES-128) in hex is 32 characters, but in base64 it would be 24 or 22 characters (depending whether you use one of the forms with or without padding). A 32-character base64 value with no padding would be 24-bytes which could be an AES-192 key but not a an AES-128 key. Plus `openssl enc -K` (and `-iv` if applicable, which it isn't here) uses hex -- read the man page.

In the old days you could just call java.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter to handle hex, but in modern Java (9 up) that is a nondefault module. Now you can (1) make your code modular, (2) use some other library, or (3) write your own -- for a simple SO post, I have done (3):

```
$ cat SO76396076.java
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

class SO76396076 {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    //String aesKeyBase64 = "BDC17ABE1F194C8DD49840C57A155013";
    //SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(aesKeyBase64), "AES");
    String aesKeyHEX = "BDC17ABE1F194C8DD49840C57A155013";
    byte[] aesKeyBin = new byte[aesKeyHEX.length()/2];
    for( int i = 0; i < aesKeyBin.length; i++ )
      aesKeyBin[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(aesKeyHEX.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBin,"AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    
    // encrypt
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal("password".getBytes());
    String encodedPassword =  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText); //returns ITmSsa+9aKeW776ABM5B+g==
    System.out.println("encrypted password = " + encodedPassword);
    
    // decrypt 
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    cipherText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode("b3JCq/QmtKSmkQABYdbiVA==".getBytes()));
    System.out.println("decrypted password = " + new String(cipherText));
  }
}

$ java SO76396076.java
encrypted password = b3JCq/QmtKSmkQABYdbiVA==
decrypted password = password
```

Also: `byte[] String.getBytes(/*noarg*/)` and `new String(byte[])` use the JVM default charset, which in all versions until recently varied by platform and user, so if you tried to use your encrypted data in anything other than a test environment this was likely to mangle data containing any non-ASCII character(s) -- which your example value doesn't, and unlike most sensitive data *passwords* usually shouldn't (but sometimes do). Java 18 up makes the default consistent at UTF-8 -- unless changed by the user(s). Thus for data in general you should still specify a suitable charset -- usually UTF-8 unless there's an application or environment specific reason for something else -- in both places; for passwords it's a closer call.